# Access Oracle 11g database remotely, windows xp server

Tags: oracle11g, remote-access

for hours now I am struggling with this. I am complete newbie to Oracle DB 11g and its really to complicated for me :).

I have installed it and it's working properly. With SQL Developer I can connect on localhost, but its not working on other machines.

**I HAVE TO USE NORMAL HOST - user/password access.**

I am trying **to use EM for editing**, since i don't want to mess up. I have set it up to work remotely. Now... I was trying to configure listener to listen on my (even) internal network IP. But its not working. I have heard about editing TNSNAMES.ORA but I can't find them in EM.

Any help please? What should I do, I am completely confused and all the time I get

> The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found easier solution.

Use Oracle Net Manager and add Listener on IP (of the machine) on the same port.
Restart, and it works.

Its the same as Venu's solution, but easier.

Comment: Also be aware of Windows XP firewall.

Answer (score 2):

In the listner.ora file under your network/admin folder, change
`HOST = localhost` to `HOST = ComputerName`.

It worked for me.

Comment: Venu, does using the computer name require DNS?  And if DNS is unavailable, should it be possible to use the IP address instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **netca** tool to configure your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files.

Make sure listener is up. Use **tnsping** tool to test connectivity.

Make sure to bounce listener after you make any changes to listener.ora. Go to windows **services** to restart listener.